# Printed output to CSV file using Python and formatting it

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

A little bit of backstory:

I have a program that allows user to enter a Name(e.g Lisbon), and based on that 
User Input's country, the program will loop through my JSON file and print out all that are relevant/falls under Lisbon's Country(e.g. Jade, John).

Here's my JSON file:

```
{  
   "user1":{  
      "Country":[  
         "China",
         "USA",
         "Nepal"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "Lisbon"
      ]
   },
   "user2":{  
      "Country":[  
         "Sweden",
         "China",
         "USA"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "Jade"
      ]
   },
   "user3":{  
      "Country":[  
         "India",
         "China",
         "USA"
      ],
      "Name":[  
         "John"
      ]
   }
}
```

I'm new to Python and I would like to know how do I export my printed results and at the same time format it nicely onto the CSV file, this is my printed results:

```
Jade : Sweden, China, USA
John : India, China, USA
```

This is how I would like it to look in the CSV file:

```
Name   Country
Jade   Sweden, China, USA
John   India, China, USA
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
def matchCountry():
    userName = raw_input("Enter user's name: ")
    with open('listOfUsers.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    def getId(name):
        for userId, v in data.items():
            if v['Name'][0].lower() == name:
                return userId;

    id = getId(userName)
    for k, v in data.items():
        if any(x in data[id]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):
            if v['Name'][0].lower() != userName.lower():
                print (v['Name'][0] + " : " + ", ".join(v['Country']))

    with open('output.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in result.items():
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this but you could consider storing the data in a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) and then writing the data to a .csv.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['John','Jane'],
              'Countries':[['Spain','India','USA'],['China','Spain','India']]})

df.to_csv('filepath_to_save',index=False)
```

This writes:

```
Countries,Names
"[Spain,India,USA]",John
"[China,Spain,India]",Jane
```

The disadvantage of this is because you have multiple values for a single column, it does not save in the most appealing format. If you knew persons would only, say, have three or less countries you could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Names':['John','Jane'],
                   'Country_one':['Spain','China'],
                   'Country_two':['India','Spain'],
                   'Country_three':['USA','India']})

# save to .csv ordering the columns
df.to_csv('filepath_to_save',index=False, header=True, 
          columns=["Names","Country_one","Country_two","Country_three"])
```

which writes:

```
Names,Country_one,Country_two,Country_three
John,Spain,India,USA
Jane,China,Spain,India
```

This will then save in a nice .csv format, but with the disadvantage of multiple

Comment: Thank you for your help! But could you help me see my code below, if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: No problem, your output is how you wanted it so it looks like your code works. My only concern would be there are two headings (Name & Country) and four data columns. Probably not considered a big issue if you are aware of it.

Comment: eh, I made the countries under one column (e.g. "Sweden, China, USA" under the column Country). That's how I wanted it to be! Thank you for all the help, I'll take note of what you said!

Answer (score 0):

I did this instead, correct me if this is bad coding or not!

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, f, lineterminator='\n')
    csvwriter.writerow(["Name", "Country"])

    for k, v in data.items():
        if any(x in data[id]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):
            if v['Name'][0].lower() != userName.lower():
                csvwriter.writerow([v['Name'][0], ", ".join(v['Country'])])
```

And this is my output in the CSV file:

```
Name   Country
Jade   Sweden, China, USA
John   India, China, USA
```

Answer (score 0):

tested for Python 3.6.7

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import os


def matchCountry():
    userName = input("Enter user's name: ")
    with open('list_of_users.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    def getId(name):
        for userId, v in data.items():
            if v['Name'][0].lower() == name:
                return userId;

    id = getId(userName)
    results = []
    for k, v in data.items():
        if any(x in data[id]['Country'] for x in v['Country']):
            if v['Name'][0].lower() != userName.lower():
                r = v['Name'][0] + "\t" + ", ".join(v['Country'])
                print(r)
                results.append(r)

    if not os.path.exists('output.csv'):
        with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            csvfile.write("Name\tCountry\n")

    with open('output.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        for row in results:
            csvfile.write(row + "\n")


def main():
    matchCountry()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```